# "One of the building" vs. "one of the buildings"

Tags: grammatical-number

I want to know which of the following is correct:

> 1. Konark is one of the famous **building** in this area
> 2. Konark is one of the famous **buildings** in this area.

My understanding is when we are talking about Konark then we should use *building* only instead *buildings* as we already specified the name of the most famous thing.

I don't understand which grammatical number to use after "one of the".

Answer (score 3):

Here the correct noun would be buildings since "one of the" is implying there are more than the one you specified and buildings here is referring to all of them not the single one.

Answer (score 1):

Use **buildings** to indicate plural.

Comment: thank for the reply.. but here we are talking about konark and it shud be used at singular(I think)..

Comment: @Priyanka When I have a bag of apples, and I give you one of them, is that then one of my apple, or one of my apples?

Comment: @oerkelens Neither. It's one of Priyanka's apples now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ........first smile of the day!.....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: let me rephrase :P Was that one of my apple or one of my apples?

Answer (score 0):

Konark belongs among the famous **buildings** in this area.

So, Kornark is one of **them**, i.e. one of the famous **buildings** in this area.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "buildings".

We hear: *one of my friends,* not: *one of my friend*.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can say it:

> 1) Konark is one of the famous buildings in this area.

(That means, there are several famous buildings in this area, and Konark is one of them.)

Or:

> 2) Konark is one famous building in this area.

That can mean the same thing, although it can take on a slightly different meaning, too, if the area has several famous landmarks, and Konark happens to be a famous building (other famous landmarks might include a famous beach, a famous river, a famous festival, a famous airport, a famous university, etc.).